# Converting TAB-files coordinate system with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, convert, coordinate-system

Is it possible to convert MapInfo TAB-files from one coordinate system to another with QGIS?

I managed to do the conversion from tab-files to shp-files so that the coordinates were converted correctly, but when I tried saving the files from tab to tab, the x-coordinate was destroyed, and all the features showed up in one vertical line. Is it possible to do the conversion properly?

Comment: You must tell more details, even better if you can provide test data.